# How to check if a json matches a struct / struct fields

Tags: json, go

Is there an easy way to check if each field of myStruct was mapped by using json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &myStruct).

The only way I could image is to define each field of a struct as pointer, otherwise you will always get back an initialized struct.
So every jsonString that is an object (even an empty one {}) will return an initialized struct and you cannot tell if the json represented your struct.

The only solution I could think of is quite uncomfortable:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Name *string `json:name`
    Age  *int    `json:age`
    Male *bool   `json:male`
}

func main() {
    var p *Person
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte("{}"), &p)
    // handle parse error
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // handle json did not match error
    if p.Name == nil || p.Age == nil || p.Male == nil {
        return
    }

    // now use the fields with dereferencing and hope you did not forget a nil check
    fmt.Println("Hello " + *p.Name)
}
```

Maybe one could use a library like [govalidator](https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator) and use SetFieldsRequiredByDefault. But then you still have to execute the validation and still you are left with the whole pointer dereferencing for value retrieval and the risk of nil pointer.

What I would like is a function that returns my unmarshaled json as a struct or an error if the fields did not match. The only thing the golang json library offers is an option to fail on unknown fields but not to fail on missing fields.

Any idea?

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? Go is not about providing magic for each and every use case which can be encapsulated into a function. Writing a function which does some work and using this function is not "uncomfortable". So what's the question?

Comment: I think it is not very handy and I haven't seen it a lot to only use pointers to struct fields, with all the dereferencing and risks of nil pointers. And about the magic:"DisallowUnknownFields" is part of the json std lib, so why couldn't "DisallowMissingFields" be? And I don't know what a function would look like that solve this generically for all structs (since a I am building a library).

Comment: First of all: pointers are not uncommon in Go. Second: Wrap this into a function. There is no need that you work with pointers, all you have to do is use them during decoding, then copy back to a "pointerless" struct. Dead simple.

Comment: So every user of the generic library has to provide two structs, has to do field == nil checks and then has to copy over to another struct... Very intuitive. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way would be to implement your own [json.Unmarshaler](http://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) which uses reflection (similar to the default json unmarshaler):

There are a few points to consider:

- if speed is of great importance to you then you should write a benchmark to see how big the impact of the extra reflection is. I suspect its negligible but it can't hurt to write a small go benchmark to get some numbers.
- the stdlib will unmarshal all numbers in your json input into floats. So if you use reflection to set integer fields then you need to provide the corresponding conversion yourself (see TODO in example below)
- the `json.Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields` function will not work as expected with your type. You need to implement this yourself (see example below)
- if you decide to take this approach you will **make your code more complex and thus harder to understand and maintain**. Are you actually sure you must know if fields are omitted? Maybe you can refactor your fields to make good usage of the zero values?

Here a fully executable test of this approach:

```
package sandbox

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
    City string
}

func (p *Person) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var m map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    v := reflect.ValueOf(p).Elem()
    t := v.Type()

    var missing []string
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        field := t.Field(i)
        val, ok := m[field.Name]
        delete(m, field.Name)
        if !ok {
            missing = append(missing, field.Name)
            continue
        }

        switch field.Type.Kind() {
        // TODO: if the field is an integer you need to transform the val from float
        default:
            v.Field(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(val))
        }
    }

    if len(missing) > 0 {
        return errors.New("missing fields: " + strings.Join(missing, ", "))
    }

    if len(m) > 0 {
        extra := make([]string, 0, len(m))
        for field := range m {
            extra = append(extra, field)
        }
        // TODO: consider sorting the output to get deterministic errors:
        // sort.Strings(extra)
        return errors.New("unknown fields: " + strings.Join(extra, ", "))
    }

    return nil
}

func TestJSONDecoder(t *testing.T) {
    cases := map[string]struct {
        in       string
        err      string
        expected Person
    }{
        "Empty object": {
            in:       `{}`,
            err:      "missing fields: Name, City",
            expected: Person{},
        },
        "Name missing": {
            in:       `{"City": "Berlin"}`,
            err:      "missing fields: Name",
            expected: Person{City: "Berlin"},
        },
        "Age missing": {
            in:       `{"Name": "Friedrich"}`,
            err:      "missing fields: City",
            expected: Person{Name: "Friedrich"},
        },
        "Unknown field": {
            in:       `{"Name": "Friedrich", "City": "Berlin", "Test": true}`,
            err:      "unknown fields: Test",
            expected: Person{Name: "Friedrich", City: "Berlin"},
        },
        "OK": {
            in:       `{"Name": "Friedrich", "City": "Berlin"}`,
            expected: Person{Name: "Friedrich", City: "Berlin"},
        },
    }

    for name, c := range cases {
        t.Run(name, func(t *testing.T) {
            var actual Person
            r := strings.NewReader(c.in)
            err := json.NewDecoder(r).Decode(&actual)
            switch {
            case err != nil && c.err == "":
                t.Errorf("Expected no error but go %v", err)
            case err == nil && c.err != "":
                t.Errorf("Did not return expected error %v", c.err)
            case err != nil && err.Error() != c.err:
                t.Errorf("Expected error %q but got %v", c.err, err)
            }

            if !reflect.DeepEqual(c.expected, actual) {
                t.Errorf("\nWant: %+v\nGot:  %+v", c.expected, actual)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this also be generic or do you need to implement this for every struct. Since the library is generic ( similar to json.Unmarshal ) und the user of the library provides arbitrary structs.

Comment: This code is in principle generic but you always need to create a custom `JSONUnmarshal` function for every type. You should be able to extract the example code I provided into a separate function which you can call but in general I advise using this approach carefully and only if you absolutely have to and otherwise default to the standard unmarshaling. 

Keep in mind you have to take care of the comment I had regarding unmarshalling numeric types. Also I didn't test unexported or anonymous fields so you should make sure to test those as well if you try this approach.

Comment: Why do you need `switch field.Type.Kind() {}` code block?

Comment: You nay not need it. The intention in my example was only to show that you can use it if you want to apply logic for specific kinds (see comment in the code)

Answer (score 1):

You could compare `p` with a empty struct, instead of comparing each field with `nil`.

```
// handle json did not match error
if p == Person{} {
    return
}
```

Since `Person{}` will initialize with the 0 value of each field, this will result in each property that is `pointers` to be `nil`, `strings` will be `""`, `ints` will be `0`, and so on.

Comment: That at least solves a little bit the problem if the nil check. But still I think it is not much fun messing around with pointers of primitive values.

Comment: But why are you using pointers, instead of values? Just pass `p` as pointer when needed? In my opinion using values is much safer since it will always have a value ( 0 value at init - for which you can check ) this will prevent panics from accessing `nil` pointers.

Comment: Btw: this does only check if *none* if the fields could be mapped. You cannot decide from the result if all fields or only some could be mapped since the check is "false" in both cases.

Comment: This does not distinguish between absent fields and present zero values.